# How to change default redirect URL of Laravel's Auth filter?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

when use beforeFilter (to verify user login status) in Controller __construct

```
$this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except'  => array('login','handleLogin'));
```

it automatically redirect guests to

```
www.example.com/login
```

how can I set redirect URL to:

```
www.example.com/user/login
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `app/filters.php` you may find something like this:

```
Route::filter('auth', function($route, $request)
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});
```

You need to change the `return Redirect::guest('login')` to this:

```
return Redirect::guest('user/login');
```

Answer (score 2):

### Laravel 5.2

If you're using Laravel 5.2 you need to open `Authenticate.php` in your `app/Http/Middleware` folder and change the `guest` function parameters to the URL path that you wish to direct them to:

`return redirect()->guest('auth/login')`

(Line 24 as of writing on clean install)

### Laravel 5.0

If you're using Laravel 5.0 you need to edit `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` in your `Http/Middleware` folder.

Change the following line to suit your needs:

`return new RedirectResponse(url('/home'));`

eg. for me the following was what I wanted:

`return new RedirectResponse(url('/'));`

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to add the following line to the default AuthController: `protected $redirectPath = '/';`

Comment: OP asks about redirects before the user is authenticated. But Google brought me here and @D.Visser 's tip was exactly what I needed. I was working with the code that Laravel's installer sets up by default and I wanted to redirect to `/` instead of `/home` after successful login.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.*

change the content of the file
app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php

`return redirect()->guest('auth/login');`

to

`return redirect()->guest('login');`

Answer (score 0):

I just wasted a few minutes of my time with this as well. I wanted to move the default login processing from `mysite.com/login` to `mysite/admin/login`, and after wondering why none of the solutions were working (I kept getting redirected to /login) I realised it's because of this line in the login.blade.php view file (Laravel 5.3):

```
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
```

It's a slight oversight on the part of the developers that despite all this wired-in cleverness they were still dumb enough to hardcode this URL into the view template... This line should really specify the 'postlogin' **named route** in `Routes.php`, ie:

```
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('postlogin') }}">
```

Now your form's action attribute will be tied to whatever URL you specify for the `postlogin` named route in `Routes.php`, ie:

```
    Route::post('login', ['as' => 'postlogin',  'uses' => 'AuthController@login'         ]);
```